# Ajax.BeginForm only displaying partial View instead of parent & partial view on return

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a parent View & a child View.

When posing with the Ajax.BeginForm, I'm expecting back the entire parent view plus the results of the partial view updated.  **Only the results of the partial view is displayed.**

In addition, the "**OnSuccess**" method doesn't seem to be getting hit as I'm debugging.

**Can someone please tell me what I'm doing incorrecty?**

### Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private DAL db = new DAL();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to YeagerTech!";

            return View();
        }

        // GET: Categories/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Categories/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Category category)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    await db.AddCategoryAsync(category);
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }

            return View(category);
        }

        public PartialViewResult ShowDetails()
        {
            //string code = Request.Form["txtCode"];
            Category cat = new Category();
            //foreach (Product p in prodList)
            //{
            //    if (p.ProdCode == code)
            //    {
            //        prod = p;
            //        break;
            //    }
            //}
            cat.CategoryID = 1;
            cat.Description = "Financial";
            return PartialView("_ShowDetails", cat);
        }

    }
```

### Parent View

```
@model Models.Models.Category

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create Category";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create Category</h2>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ShowDetails", "Home", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    UpdateTargetId = "div1",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    OnSuccess = "OnSuccess",
    OnFailure = "OnFailure"
}, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
        <div class="body-content">
            <h4>Category</h4>
            <hr />
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-offset-1 col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Description" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11">
                    <button type="submit" id="btnCategoryCreate" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>Create</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
}

    <div id="div1">

    </div>

    @*<div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        @Html.Hidden("categoryCreateUrl", Url.Action("Create", "Home"))
    </div>*@

    @section Scripts {
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function ()
            {
                function OnSuccess(response)
                {
                    $('#form1').trigger("reset");
                }

                //if (typeof contentCreateCategory == "function")
                //    contentCreateCategory();
            });
        </script>
    }
```

### Partial View

```
@model Models.Models.Category

    <h1>Cat Details</h1>
    <h2>
        Cat Code: @Model.CategoryID<br />
        Cat Name: @Model.Description<br />
    </h2>
```

### EDIT # 1

Parent & child view displayed (due to a missing JS file, thanks to the mention of Stephen), plus was able to programmatically clear out the form with the OnSuccess method.

I had thought since that was JS, it needed to go in the Scripts section, but did not recognize it there.

Here is the finished code.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ShowDetails", "Home", new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        UpdateTargetId = "div1",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        OnSuccess = "OnSuccess",
        OnFailure = "OnFailure"
    }, new { @id = "frm1", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <div class="body-content">
        <h4>Category</h4>
        <hr />
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-offset-1 col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Description" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11">
                <button type="submit" id="btnCategoryCreate" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>Create</button>
                <button type="reset" id="btnClear" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close"></span>Clear</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div id="div1">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function OnSuccess(response)
    {
        $('#frm1').trigger("reset");
    }

    function OnFailure(response)
    {
        alert("Whoops! That didn't go so well did it?");
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Your `Ajax.BeginForm` will only return a partial view because that's what the method your calling returns. But I suspect the problem is that you have not included the relevant js files so its doing a standard submit instead of ajax. Ensure you have included `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` in the main view

Comment: Thanks Stephen; that was it! See my edit...

Answer (score 2):

A bit late for answer, but yet it might help someone else.

The issue might be that the javascript files required for Ajax.BeginForm are not loaded in your page.

> Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax

Nuget package to search for

```
<package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
```

of course that the version might differ.

Add reference to the page after your jQuery and it should work.